# Validating a ISO_8601 full date with momentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, iso8601

I have the following code:

```
moment(dateValue, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()
```

Which works well, except for when i only have a date with the year and the month, i.e `2020-07`, it still returns `true`.

How can i make it return `true` only if the value consists of **at least** a full date? (i.e `2020-07-15`)

Comment: What is the **_actual_** value of `dateValue` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just define your own `ISO_8601` format constant. The value of `moment.ISO_8601` is a function which allows for partial timestamps. If you want to be strict, you just supply your own. I am reusing the HTML5 built-in "local-date" constants and appending a timezone option `"Z"` to the end.

```js
const ISO_8601 = moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_MS + 'Z';
const dateValue = new Date().toISOString();

// Valid
console.log(dateValue, '?', moment(dateValue, ISO_8601, true).isValid());

// Invalid
const yearMonth = dateValue.substring(0, 7);
console.log(yearMonth, '?', moment(yearMonth, ISO_8601, true).isValid());

// Valid
const ymd = dateValue.substring(0, 10);
console.log(ymd, '?', moment(ymd, moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE, true).isValid());

// Valid
const ts = '2012-02-02T13:30-01:00';
const format = moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL + 'Z';
console.log(ts, '?', moment(ts, format, true).isValid());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Where:

- `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_MS` ⇒ `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS"`
- `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE` ⇒ `"YYYY-MM-DD"`

---

Here are all built-in [HTML5 formats](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.27.0/src/moment.js#L81) for moment (starting with version 2.20.0). These constants were [added](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/4154/files) on December 16, 2017.

```js
// currently HTML5 input type only supports 24-hour formats
hooks.HTML5_FMT = {
    DATETIME_LOCAL: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm', // <input type="datetime-local" />
    DATETIME_LOCAL_SECONDS: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss', // <input type="datetime-local" step="1" />
    DATETIME_LOCAL_MS: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS', // <input type="datetime-local" step="0.001" />
    DATE: 'YYYY-MM-DD', // <input type="date" />
    TIME: 'HH:mm', // <input type="time" />
    TIME_SECONDS: 'HH:mm:ss', // <input type="time" step="1" />
    TIME_MS: 'HH:mm:ss.SSS', // <input type="time" step="0.001" />
    WEEK: 'GGGG-[W]WW', // <input type="week" />
    MONTH: 'YYYY-MM', // <input type="month" />
};
```

Comment: And what if i want a full date (`YYYY-MM-DD` only) with or without time and/or timezone?

Comment: @Gambit2007 Then validate it using `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE`. I updated my example to include that validation.

Comment: But then the validation for time and timezone would fail.. with time: `2012-02-02T13:30`, with timezone: `2012-02-02T13:30-01:00`

Comment: @Gambit2007 ISO-8601 does not concern itself with time zone identifiers.

Comment: So i can i make a value like `2012-02-02T13:30-01:00` pass validation?

Comment: @Gambit2007 I updated the response with more details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add format function call and specify the format you want to check.

`const date = moment(dateValue, moment.ISO_8601, true).format('DD-MM-YYYY') moment(date).isValid()`

Have you tried this yet?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `.format(...).isValid is not a function`

Comment: That's because `moment.prototype.format(pattern)` returns a `String`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, i have not tested it, but I wonder if you could do something like that.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh it's not working - `2020-07` still returns `true`.